# Google Analytics API & Service Accounts Authentication

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Preface: I work at an agency with access to many clients google analytics accounts. I am working to set up an API to pipe all the clients data to a data warehouse.When I try to use the python API library, I created a service account that needs to be added as a user by each client. This can take a while depending on the client.

Question: why is it that if I wanted to use something like [stitch data](https://www.stitchdata.com/), that they can access all of my client's data without having a service account of theirs added to each individual client? How does the singer-tap used for this work to avoid this service account problem?

Comment: You should not be using a service account for access to any account that is not controlled directly by you.  You should be using Oauth2 and having your clients authorize your application and storing the refresh token.

Comment: @DaImTo - What would the python code look like for something like this? I'm trying to do the same thing, but can't find the documentation to support this without having to build a service account.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py or https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-py

Comment: @DaImTo - Thanks for the response! I'll give the installed version a try. Thank you!

Comment: Tip that sample is single user. your going to have to come up with something for storing credentials for more then one user check storage = file.Storage('analyticsreporting.dat')